# How can I scale/clip a drawable to the largest axis?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a square drawable image (drawable-l is 1280x1280) and I want it to crop depending on which direction the device is in (landscape, portrait). I want the image to always be centered, scaled to fill the largest side, and have the smaller side clipped.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

Adding on to Pramod J George's answer below, if you take the ImageView with the scaleType:centerCrop and put it along side your main layout inside of a FrameLayout, this will work perfectly!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do some help

http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/22/to-scale-or-not-to-scale/